# MVC4 how to use multimedia plugin

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

I'm building a site with songs and video upload, (similar to mySpace) so the file is stored in a folder inside the project. I'm trying to use the following plugin to play those songs: 
http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/
but it's asking to add "ExternalInterface.addCallback()" if the file is played locally. Where should I add this callback??
I'm new in the MVC4 world so any hand is wellcome :)

here is my Model: Song.cs

```
namespace VPM.Models
{
//db model
public class Song 
{
    [Key]
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string songName { get; set; }
    public string songPath { get; set; }
    public int like { get; set; }
    public int unlike { get; set; }
    public Boolean share { get; set; }

}
public class UploadMusic
{
    [Required]
    public int userId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string songName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string songPath { get; set; }

    public Song getSong()
    {
        Song u = new Song { userId = this.userId, songName = this.songName, songPath = this.songPath };
        return u;
    }
}
```

}

here is my controller - SongsController.cs

```
public class SongsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Songs/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            VPMDB db = new VPMDB();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
            String email ="";
            var query = from u in db.users where u.userId.Equals(id) select u.Email;
            bool flag = false;

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                flag = true;
                email = item;
            }
            //if user exists 
            if (flag)
            {

                string UserDirectory = "C:\\Users\\dadaPC\\Desktop\\VPM\\VPM\\VPM\\UserFiles\\" + email + "\\music\\" + file.FileName.ToString();
                file.SaveAs(UserDirectory);  
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                UploadMusic newsong = new UploadMusic();
                newsong.userId = 11;
                newsong.songName = file.FileName.ToString();
                newsong.songPath = UserDirectory;

                db.song.Add(newsong.getSong());
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


}
```

and here is my view - index.cshtml

```
@model VPM.Models.Song

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Your Music</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Songs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" />
}

<script src="/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
<script>
  audiojs.events.ready(function() {
      var as = audiojs.createAll();
  });
</script>

<audio src="file:///C:/Users/dadaPC/Desktop/VPM/VPM/VPM/UserFiles/da@aa.com/music/01 A Word From The Author.mp3" preload="auto" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the comments on the page, you will see that this is a security issue.  Read the last paragraph below.

> Note: For local content running in a browser, calls to the ExternalInterface.addCallback() method work only if the SWF file and the containing web page are in the local-trusted security sandbox.
>
> From: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()
>
> This means that unless you have gone through the rigmarole of setting up your flash player security settings for local files, ExternalInterface calls will only work when the page is loaded from a ‘domain’. `http://localhost` counts, but any `file://` requests don’t.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstand that. what do you recommend for this case? use the html <audio> control?

Comment: @122333123183 - I assume this is only for testing purposes?  Your users won't be using it on local files?

Comment: this is project for college, where you can either upload a music file or a youtube link, and play it.

Comment: @122333123183 - Yes, but you want them to play it from the server, not from their local computers.. right?